# Parse the gemfile and get all the gems used in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Im writing a script to get all gems from the gemfile from a rails project.Script goes something like this

```
     @gem_file_path=File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __FILE__) || ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']      ||  Dir.pwd + "/Gemfile"
     File.open(gem_file_path).read.each_line do |i|
 i=i.split
      if i[0] == "gem" && i[0].start_with?("gem")
        name = i[1].gsub(",","") 
        gem_name= eval name
        author_email_id=Gem::Specification.find_by_name(gem_name.to_s).email
        author_name=Gem::Specification.find_by_name(gem_name).author
      end
     end
```

Is there a better way to do it ? Because i also get issues when something like below is mentioned in gemfile and other possibilities too

```
        gem 'rspec-rails',:group => [:test,:development]
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could run "bundle show" within your project directory and save the return value for parsing to avoid parsing the gemfile directly and take care of special cases like your last example. Run the shell command in your script. But I have not tried it by myself yet..

Answer (score 6):

For anyone stumbling across this question years later like myself, I found that you can get access to the gems referenced in the Gemfile without actually running the gemfile by doing something like the following:

```
Bundler::Definition.build('Gemfile', nil, {}).dependencies
```

'Gemfile' here should be the path to the Gemfile from the current file.

Credit goes to Troy Verbrugge for digging into the bundler code.

Comment: This runs the ruby code in Gemfile so use with caution

Answer (score 2):

use something like this:

```
repos = Gem.loaded_specs.values
repos.each do |repo|
  g_em = repo.name
  s_ource = repo.source
end
```

Comment: This does not parse the Gemfile. It lists all the gems included in the Gemfile.lock, not the Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to parse from Gemfile.lock given. Then the below is a tip for me:

> Bundler::LockfileParser.new(Bundler.read_file("Gemfile.lock"))

Answer (score 0):

Gemnasium-parser might be a good solution

https://github.com/gemnasium/gemnasium-parser

You can also use Bundler to do it directly, but you run the risk of evaluating ruby code you don't know is in there.

You can also use Bundler to parse the Gemfile.lock which avoids the eval issue.

Comment: I'd avoid using gemnasium. that uses regular expressions fails to parse commands like if. I'd go with bundler

Comment: This library is no longer maintained.